# Can't parse Java JSON string

Tags: java, json

From my server is get a JSON response like this:

```
String json = getJsonFromServer();
```

The server returns this reply (with the double quotes in the beginning and end):

```
"{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}";
```

I then want to get the error field. I have tried to use the JSONObject class to get the string, but it does not work.

```
System.out.println("The error is: " + new JSONObject().getJSONObject(response).getString("error");
```

Comment: please see my edit now that you have changed the question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong [`JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-) constructor; in your example, you are trying to fetch an object from a newlay created object - it will never exist.

Try this:

```
String response = "{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject( response );

String error = json.getString( "error" );

System.out.println( error );
```

Yields

> Not all required fields have been filled out

**edit**

Now that you have completely changed the question...

Why not just first strip the first and last char?

So if

```
String response = "\"{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}\"";

response = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1));

// Now convert to JSONObject
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? I just tried this with [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810).

Comment: Same library as you. Just found out when I go new JSONObject(response) it does not work. When I hardcode the value and go JSONObject("{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}") it does work. There seems to be an issue then with the backslashes I suppose and quotes?

Comment: I am voting to close your question as I am unsure what you are asking, or what your error actually is. The above example works with the above posted code; if there is another error, then you have posted incorrect data. Edit your question to include the **actual** response string, and the **actual** error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your response object has exactly this string?

**{"error":"Not all required fields have been filled out"}**

The code below printed the expected output:

```
    Object responseObject = "{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseObject.toString());
    String errorContent = jsonObject.getString("error");
    System.out.println(errorContent);
```

Comment: No, my exact response I get from the server is "{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}". It has double quotes in front of it.

Comment: It means that the server response is an **Object** , in the code I publish call the method toString in the Object, like this: **responseObject.toString()**

Answer (score 0):

I have try

```
String response = "{\"error\":\"Not all required fields have been filled out\"}";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response);

        System.out.println(json.get("error").toString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }
```

It have working, you can try it and don't forget add json lib [json-simple](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code isn't mine and I unfortunately can't add any third part libraries.